# Firebird SQL challenge - return one row that has the data when select returned two rows

Tags: sql, firebird

I have a quite unique need to make select always return one row

My SQL:

```
select * from table1 Where (table1.pk = :p1) or (table1.fk1 = :p1)
```

The above SQL always has two cases for return:

1- my Select return two records:
The only different is one of the records has data while the other has only the ID filled with data while the rest of its fields are null. I need in this case to return **only** the one that has data in other fields.

2- my Select return one record 
In this case the record returned has only the ID field filled with data while the rest of the fields are null however this is what I want and no need for any further processing.

Please advise if is it possible to do that in one plain Select SQL. I can not use stored procedure.

Comment: can you give sample records?

Comment: @JW. ID = any integer the rest of the fields some are integers and some are varchar. jachguate solution is very close to what I need I think I may use it. thanks

Comment: Very close? what am I missing?

Comment: @jachguate I did not ment you missing something but I am still testing few options.....thanks alot for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `first` clause of the `select` statement to get only 1 row.

Given your specific conditions, you can order the result set descending by the *rest of the fields* to be sure the null row is selected only in case there's no data row (null goes first in firebird 2.5, but AFAIK this changed somewhere in the last versions, so check your specific version before applying this).

Your final query will look like this:

```
select first 1 * 
  from table1 
 where (table1.pk = :p1) 
    or (table1.fk1 = :p1)
 order by somecolumn;
```

`somecolumn` being the most relevant of the *other fields* that can contain null values.

you can test this with this statements:

```
--two rows, one with ID and values and the other with ID and null
with q1 as (
      select 1 id, 'data' othercolumn
        from rdb$database
      union
      select 2 id, null othercolumn
        from rdb$database
     ) 
select first 1 *
  from q1
 order by othercolumn nulls last;

--versus:

--onw row with ID and null
with q1 as (
      select 2 id, null othercolumn
        from rdb$database
     ) 
select first 1 *
  from q1
 order by othercolumn nulls last;
```

Comment: yes jachguate your solution worked !! and when I used `desc` I get the record that has the data when two records returned. but can I depend on this behavior in upcoming versions ? I use currently FB 2.51.xxxx

Comment: I found that I can use `order by 2 nulls last` to make sure nulls always come last

Comment: IMHO you could leave it as is, because that's the SQL standard and the database is now compliant, but you can add it to be sure, just in case.

Comment: @jachguate: the SQL standard does *not* define an order for NULL values. It's up to the DBSM implementation. The only way to guarantee the order is to use `NULLS FIRST` and `NULLS LAST`. Although I doubt the behaviour will "suddenly" change given a specific DBMS.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It changed between Firebird 1.x and Firebird 2.x, see http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-select.html#langrefupd25-orderby section 'NULLs placement'

Comment: Thanks for the link @Mark. I remembered that the change had been to meet the standard, but I was obviously wrong. Anyway, it's difficult it changes again in the future.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: thanks, I wasn't aware of that. I never used Firebird 1.x