# other solution than case when

Tags: sql, case-when

I have a firebird database and this query:

```
select distinct
 case
  when exists (select * from fixvar
               where costtype_id=7 and extract(year from ct_from)<=2017 and
               2017<=extract(year from ct_to) and costcenter_id=10)
  then (select fix from fixvar where costtype_id=7 and extract(year from ct_from)<=2017 and
               2017<=extract(year from ct_to) and costcenter_id=10)
  else (select fix from fixvar where costtype_id=7 and extract(year from ct_from)<=2017 and
               2017<=extract(year from ct_to))
 end as fix,
 case
  when exists (select * from fixvar
               where costtype_id=7 and extract(year from ct_from)<=2017 and
               2017<=extract(year from ct_to) and costcenter_id=10)
  then (select var from fixvar where costtype_id=7 and extract(year from ct_from)<=2017 and
               2017<=extract(year from ct_to) and costcenter_id=10)
  else (select var from fixvar where costtype_id=7 and extract(year from ct_from)<=2017 and
               2017<=extract(year from ct_to) and costcenter_id=10)
 end as var
from fixvar
```

I get the right result, but can I do it shorter?

What I want: I would like to query the fields `fix` and `var`. If there is a row, where the `costcenter_id` is `10`, then I want to have the corresponding `fix` and `var` values, if not, then the values, where we haven't a `costcenter_id` (-1).

EDIT:

Sample data:

[image]

As you see, there is two rows. So, if a row exists with `costcenter_id=10`, then I want the appr. `fix` and `var` values, if there is no row with this `costcenter_id`, then I want the `fix` and `var` values, where the `costcenter_id=-1`.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help explain what you want to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebird SQL challenge - return one row that has the data when select returned two rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14451183/firebird-sql-challenge-return-one-row-that-has-the-data-when-select-returned-t)

Comment: Thanks Serg, that brough me to the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, I have the solution:

```
select
 first 1 fix, var, costcenter_id
from 
 fixvar
where
 costtype_id=7 
and 
 2017 between extract(year from ct_from) and extract(year from ct_to)
and
 costcenter_id in (-1, 10)
order by costcenter_id desc
```